# How can i change the playback speed of an mp3?

Tags: c#, cscore

I have an mp3 file which i load into a memorystream and then, after some code, i play it. How can i change the playback speed to x1.4?

Current code:

```
DirectSoundOut SoundOut = new DirectSoundOut();
byte[] TargetFile = File.ReadAllBytes("PathToFile");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(TargetFile);
SoundOut.Initialize(new CSCore.Codecs.MP3.DmoMp3Decoder(ms));
SoundOut.Volume = 1;
SoundOut.Play();
```

Comment: just a hunch, but you're setting the bit rate.  Maybe you can lie.  Let me know how this library works for you.  I'm trying to get a good way to read music beats.

Comment: until this question gets answered i am using NAudio with rubberband